# Show that $2 \operatorname{Re}(z-1/z) > 1/|z|^2 - 1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $z$ be a root of $x^n-x-1.$ Show that $2 \operatorname{Re}(z-1/z) > 1/|z|^2 - 1$.

*Solution*. Write $z = re^{i\theta}, r > 0$ as $0$ is obviously not a root. Then $$1+2r\cos \theta = |z+1|^2-r^2 = r^{2n} - r^2.$$ We need to show that $$2(r\cos\theta - 1/r \cos \theta) =  2 \operatorname{Re}(re^{i\theta} - 1/r e^{-i\theta}) > 1/r^2 - 1.$$ We know that $2r\cos \theta = r^{2n}-r^2 - 1\Rightarrow \cos \theta = \dfrac{r^{2n}-r^2-1}{2r}$ from above. So we need to show that $$r^{2n}-r^2 - 1 - \dfrac{r^{2n}-r^2-1}{r^2} > 1/r^2 - 1\Leftrightarrow r^{2n+2} - r^4 - r^2 - r^{2n} + r^2 + 1 - 1 + r^2>0 \\ \Longleftrightarrow r^{2n+2} - r^{2n} - r^4 + r^2 = r^2(r^{2n} - r^{2n-2} -r^2 + 1).$$

I don't think I've made any algebraic mistakes, so I was wondering how I can show the last quantity is positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n>1$ and your last parenthesis is $(r^2-1)(r^{2n-2}-1),$ so you just have to prove that $r\ne1.$

Let us prove it by contradiction. If $r=1$ then (by what you already proved) $\cos\theta=-\frac12$ hence $z=e^{\pm i2\pi/3},$ but such a $z$ satisfies $z+1=-z^2\ne z^n.$

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove that $$r^{2n}+1>r^{2n-2}-r^2\tag{1}$$ which is easy to see since $r^{2n}>r^{2n-2}$ (when $r>1$, that is) and so the inequality is proven for $r>1$. When $r<1$ we have $r^{2n-2}<r^2$ so the right side of $(1)$ is negative and the left side is positive. Therefore your inequality is true.